# PUT Request fails on field rename

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Serializer.py

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    id = serializers.IntegerField(source='category_id')
    name = serializers.CharField(source='category_name')

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['id', 'name']
```

Above works fine for the GET but when i run PUT request it goes to fail block

views.py for PUT

```
request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = CategorySerializer(category, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            response = {
                'status': status.HTTP_200_OK,
                'message' : "Category Updated",
            }
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type='application/json')
        else :
            response = {
                'status': status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                'message' : "Category not found",
            }
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type='application/json')
```

And i'm running following curl

curl -X PUT http://localhost:8000/api/add-category/4/ -d "category_name=xyz"

Response:

```
{"status": 400, "message": "Category not found"}
```

Each time it goes in else part.

Experts please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't attach your's serializer errors, but it looks like that you should set `partial` argument for `PUT` request method.
Try

```
serializer = CategorySerializer(category, data=request.data, partial=True)
```

Documentation [link](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#partial-updates)

Answer (score 0):

I think problem with `id` field, it is required. But you sent only `name` field, try to use `partial` key.

```
serializer = CategorySerializer(category, data=request.data, partial=True)
```